# How can I insert and update foreign key table rows in efcore

Tags: entity-framework-core

> The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

```
agentDetail.AgentGDS_AccessDetails.ForEach(x => x.Deleted = false); //Update the record in table

agentDetailView.AgentGDS_AccessDetails
    .ForEach(agentGDS_AccessDetailView =>
    {
        AgentGDS_AccessDetail agentGDS_AccessDetail = new AgentGDS_AccessDetail();

        agentGDS_AccessDetail.GDS_AccessId = Guid.NewGuid();
        agentGDS_AccessDetail.GDS_Id       = agentGDS_AccessDetailView.GDS_Id;
        agentGDS_AccessDetail.PCC          = agentGDS_AccessDetailView.PCC;
        agentGDS_AccessDetail.Description  = agentGDS_AccessDetailView.Description;
                            
        agentDetail.AgentGDS_AccessDetails.Add(agentGDS_AccessDetail); //add the new record to table
    });

_unitOfWork.Complete();//I can't able to update the record. it throws error
```

Comment: Does an updated row exist in the database?

Comment: Yes serhii the row is existing on database

Comment: And what's your `DbContext` configuration?